# How to set a javascript var as undefined

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
console.log(boo); this outputs undefined
```

Given:

```
var boo = 1;
console.log(boo); this outputs 1
```

After defining boo and setting to 1, how can I then reset boo, so that console.log outputs undefined?

Thanks

Comment: just don't do this. null is a better option.

Comment: @coldtree Please change your accepted answer  to gooseberry's answer

Comment: Colin's answer is also very good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24748543/3768862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete boo`

Don't use `var boo = undefined`. undefined is just a variable and if someone sets `undefined = "hello"` then you'll be getting hello everywhere :)

**EDIT:**

null wasn't same as undefined. removed that bit.

Comment: You cannot `delete boo`, it's a variable. It only works if the variable is in global scope and even then it doesn't work in IE and throws an error in strict mode.

Comment: Please be aware that this may not work in every JavaScript runtime environment. I tried this in Node.js and it did not work.

Comment: Esailija is correct. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): "`delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names."

Answer (score 50):

## Solution

To reliably set a variable `boo` to `undefined`, use a function with an empty `return` expression:

```
boo = (function () { return; })();
```

After executing this line of code, `typeof(boo)` evaluates to `'undefined'`, regardless of whether or not the `undefined` global property has been set to another value.  For example:

```
undefined = 'hello';
var boo = 1;
console.log(boo); // outputs '1'
boo = (function () { return; })();
console.log(boo); // outputs 'undefined'
console.log(undefined); // outputs 'hello'
```

**EDIT** But see also @Colin's [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748543/3768862)!

## Reference

This behavior is standard as far back as ECMAScript 1.  The relevant specification states in part:

> **Syntax**
>
> **`return`** [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression* ;
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A **`return`** statement causes a function to cease execution and return a value to the caller. If *Expression* is omitted, the return value is **`undefined`**.

To view the original specifications, refer to:

- [ECMAScript 5.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9)
- [JavaScript (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Parameters)

## Appendix

For completeness, I have appended a brief summary of alternate approaches to this problem, along with objections to these approaches, based on the answers and comments given by other responders.

### 1. Assign `undefined` to `boo`

```
boo = undefined; // not recommended
```

Although it is simpler to assign `undefined` to `boo` directly, `undefined` is not a reserved word and [could be replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795936/how-to-set-a-javascript-var-as-undefined#answer-5795984) by an arbitrary value, such as a number or string.

### 2. Delete `boo`

```
delete boo; // not recommended
```

Deleting `boo` removes the definition of `boo` entirely, rather than assigning it the value `undefined`, and even then [only works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795936/how-to-set-a-javascript-var-as-undefined#comment-15469608) if `boo` is a global property.

Comment: Regarding your appendix item 1: from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined): "In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), `undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification." So `boo = undefined;` is safe in "modern browsers" because `undefined` cannot be overridden.

Comment: isn't the return statement redundant? This worked for me:
`_foo = (function () {})();`

Comment: @AndreschSerj  That worked for me too. The return statement is redundant. My IDE also complained about it :)

Comment: See also Colin's simpler solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24748543/3768862).

Answer (score 44):

Use the `void` operator. It will evaluate it's expression and then return `undefined`. It's idiomatic to use `void 0` to assign a variable to `undefined`

```
var boo = 1; // boo is 1
boo = void 0; // boo is now undefined
```

Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 16):

You can simply assign a variable the value of undefined:

```
boo = undefined;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `delete` operator to delete the variable:

```
delete boo;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var boo = 1;
console.log(boo); // prints 1
boo = undefined;
console.log(boo); // now undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on Chrome Javascript Console:

```
delete(boo)
```